# Tomar foto y guardarla full size no bitmap

Tags: android, imagen, android-intent

Buenas, quisiera que me ayuden, como puedo hacer para tomar una foto y guardarla (no el bitmap) la foto en full size, por ejemplo como hace whatsapp, que crea una carpeta en el movil, he visto varias paginas donde muestran como guardar en la sd card, pero que pasa si el movil no tiene sd card.

Comment: Hola edwin, bienvenido a SO en español. Te sugiero que tomes el [tour] para entender el funcionamiento del sitio y [ask] para realizar preguntas de mayor calidad y con un mejor recibimiento por parte de la comunidad.

Comment: Es una pregunta de muy simple investigación; https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: La [documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) explica perfectamente cómo crear el intent con el parámetro adicional `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` para que se guarde la foto en la URI que se pasa como parametro.